# object not found in summarise with macro(function) in r

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying make macro with `function` and `dplyr`.

What I'm trying to do is `summarise` specific variable. In `function`, the variable is `i`. the age is in the `dataset`

```
fun<-function(i){
dataset%>%dplyr::summarise(t1=mean(i),t2=sd(i))
}
fun(i=age)
```

When I executed `summarise` without `function`, it worked. However, with `function`, the error appeared.

```
 Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'age' not found
```

Can anybody help me know what was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `{{}}` operator to evaluate the unquoted column name passed into the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
fun<-function(datasset, i){
   dataset%>%
        dplyr::summarise(t1=mean({{i}}),
                         t2=sd({{i}})
 }
fun(dataset, age)
```

---

Or another option is to use `enquo` and evaluate (`!!`)

```
fun<-function(dataset, i){
   i <- enquo(i)
   dataset%>%
        dplyr::summarise(t1=mean(!!i),
                         t2=sd(!!i))
 }
fun(dataset, age)
```

NOTE: It may be better to pass the data object as well as argument to function

Comment: Really thanks!!! However, in first statement(using {{}}) maybe mean({{i}}) is right. not just {{i}}. right? without (), the error appeared.

Comment: Thanks. I can't accept the answer before 10 minutes due to stackoverflow policy. After 10 minutes, I will accept it.