# invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid contents of {}' in function with R

Tags: r, function

I'm making macro with `function`

`mytable` in `moonBook` package will be used in `function` macro. `mytable` function makes descriptive table of population quickly.

```
fun<-function(i,j)
  {
j<-mytable(i~var1+var2+var3,data=rawdata)
return(j)
}
fun(i=criteria,j=out)
```

However, the error appeared.

' i ' is an invalid column name: Instead ' (other value name) ' is used

I thought that `mytable` function can't recognize the macro object, `i`.

With help of this post ([object not found in summarise with macro(function) in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59152388/object-not-found-in-summarise-with-macrofunction-in-r)) I put the double parentheses around `i`.

But the error appeared again.

```
 Error in grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression, reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

I tried `enquo` and `!!`. But error still appeared.

```
 Error in which(grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = TRUE)) : 
  argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Please help me know what was the problem.

Comment: R is not a macro language.

Comment: Isn't that 'function' generally called macro?

Comment: Here I use the term macro for code that modifies code before that code gets parsed and evaluated. You mistakenly believed that R would replace the `i` in your function body with `criteria` before parsing the function body. That's what macro languages do. In R, you can do something similar by computing on the language (although that happens after parsing) but that's an advanced topic and is not a natural first approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the function, may be we need a formula and it can be created with `paste`

```
fun<-function(i) {

    mytable(as.formula(paste0(i, " ~var1+var2+var3")),data=rawdata)
 }

fun(i= "criteria")
```

NOTE: The 'j' argument is not needed as we don't need to create an object and then `return` it.  In `R`, explicitly defining `return` is not required